# Is there something like a (readied) charge in 5e?

Tags: dnd-5e, combat

We're moving from D&D 3.5e to 5e. In 3.5 games there usually was a lot of charging going on, and DMs would also (as a house rule) allow partial charges as readied actions (nothing more dramatic then readying a charge triggered by a charging opponent!).

In 5e the Charge action seems to be gone entirely (at least, I haven't found it in either the Basic Rules or the PHB). On your own turn I guess that's no problem because you can easily *roleplay* charge (simply move + attack), and if reasonable the DM could give you *Advantage* on your attack.

However, with *Ready* it's a different thing. It almost seems as if I'm asking a 5e-version of [this existing 3.5e question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/5859/2965), because the rules on *Ready* say (emphasis mine):

> First you decide what perceivable circumstance will trigger your reaction. Then you **choose the action you will take** in response to that trigger, ***or* choose to move up to your speed** in response to it.

So I guess you can only *either* attack *or* move as a readied action, thus excluding a (partial) charge. This would be a shame, because I'd hate to miss the cool drama that comes with readied charges.

Solution would be simple, but I still have to ask: do we need a house rule for readied charges in 5e too?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Charging in 5e is done through the optional *feats*.

Via page 165 of the *PHB*;

> ## Charger
>
> When you use your action to Dash, you can use a bonus action to make one melee weapon attack or to shove a creature.
>   If you move at least  10 feet in a straight line immediately before taking this bonus action, you either gain a +5 bonus to the attack’s damage roll (if you chose to make a melee attack and hit) or push the target up to  10 feet away from you (if you chose to shove and you succeed).

I can't find anything in the *DMG* for an optional charging rule either so, as per the rules, sacrificing your *Ability Score Increase* for said *Feat* is the only option you have to gain the ability to *charge*.

As for *readying* a charge, as per @Miniman's response to [my question,](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/53827/can-you-use-a-bonus-action-on-a-turn-other-than-your-own) *bonus actions* can only be used on **your** turn, which means you can *ready* a *Dash action* (which wouldn't be of any help since *Dash* doesn't provide any movement itself) but would be unable to take the *bonus action to make one melee weapon attack or to shove a creature*.

Comment: Ahh, yes I see the rules now. Weird that the index doens't include "Charger" :P. In any case we'll need to create a house rule then to allow readied charges.

Comment: It might be worth noting that the reason that charging was relegated to a feat is because spring attack/ride by attack are the default stance now, and it is possible to move over 10' per attack for multiple attacks in this edition. This would have the possibility of greatly overpowering the charge attack. It is best relegated, considering this, to be a feat for a partial solution instead. You can still use your readied move to intercept an enemy when they reach a threshold (like opening a door) and attack on your action. That still has tactical weight to it, and *almost* ends up like a charge.

Comment: @PurpleMonkey Think we'll have to agree to disagree on the index thing then :).

Comment: @Aviose That's a good point. I dislike the readied move-to-intercept though, it just doesn't have the drama clashing steel from opposed charges has. In any case, the rules are clear (which is nice) and we can always see if a house rule is warranted.

Comment: The simplest house-rule would be to state that if you have the charger feat you can use your bonus action outside of your turn on a readied dash.

Comment: @PurpleMonkey A dash allows you to move up to your speed. Readying a dash should provide that movement to use quickly. Of course, it could be noted that simply using a move is the equivalent *unless* feats like charger were allowed.

Comment: @PurpleMonkey hmm.... I don't recall the exact text... If that's the case then all it would do is give you a boost on your next turn, at best.

Comment: @Aviose Even if you can ready a Dash, would you be able to take a bonus action on someone else's turn?

Comment: @acbabis technically and normally, no. This is where DM and player working together for a houserule is the only real solution to achieve intent.

Answer (score -4):

I also really missed charging in 5e, so I decided to change the rules for both Dash and the Charger feat in my current campaign, take a look.

> **Dash action:** When you take the Dash action, you gain extra movement for the current turn. The increase equals your speed, after applying any modifiers. With a speed of 30 feet, for example, you can move up to 60 feet on your turn if you dash. ***You can use your bonus action to make a melee  attack or shove a creature at the end of your dash.***
>
> Any increase or decrease to your speed changes this additional movement by the same amount. If your speed of 30 feet is reduced to 15 feet, for instance, you can move up to 30 feet this turn if you dash.

> **Charger:** When you use your action to Dash, ***you don´t use your bonus action*** (Like the H. R. for dash) to make one melee weapon attack or to shove a creature. If you move at least 10 feet in a straight line immediately before taking this bonus action, you either gain a +5 bonus to the attack’s damage roll (if you chose to make a melee attack and hit) or push the target up to 10 feet away from you (if you chose to shove and you succeed).

I thought it would still be cool to have this feat, because you can use your bonus action to make another type of attack, such as dual wielding, or cast a bonus action spell at the end of your Dash.

Comment: Welcome to rpg.se! Please take a look at the [tour](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour) and the [help center](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/help); they're a useful introduction to the site. Did you tried the rules you propose?

Comment: Since this site isn't a discussion forum, we cannot discuss your homebrew material or give feedback on it. I've removed the request for feedback (and also did some formatting). If you'd like feedback on your material, we suggest using a discussion forum; we have [a list of such forums](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5449/ive-been-told-my-question-is-better-suited-to-a-forum-but-where-should-i-go) that you might choose from.